# How I should get token and send it in API request in redux/toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I just migrate to redux/toolkit and I'm a little confused about obtain the token of the user because I'm not sure if I'm doing right in only calling the local storage instead of getState() as I usually do before with the previous redux.

This is the code:

```
// VideoSlice

const user: User = localStorage.getItem('user') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!) : null;

export const uploadVideo = createAsyncThunk("videos/uploadStatus", async ( input: VideoInput , thunkApi) => {

    try {

        return await videoService.uploadVideo(input, user.token);

    } catch (error: any) {
        const message = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
        return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(message);
    }

});

// VideoService

// AXIOS
import Axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = '/api/video';

const uploadVideo = async ( input: VideoInput, token: string ) => {

    const { data } = await Axios.post(`${API_URL}`, input, {
        headers: {
            'x-token': token
        }
    });

    return data;

}

const videoService = {
    getVideos,
    uploadVideo,
}

export default videoService;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are keeping the token in localstorage then you can leverage that for API call, you can also get the state using thunkAPI.

```
const {user}=thunkAPI.getState().auth   //assuming you have the auth slice with an user and its token properties
const {token}=user
```

But again, on page refresh the redux state is lost so local storage has to be used.